# ToggleButton Initializing object with Dynamic property names

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When the user toggles the buttons, I need to fire the `handleChange` method, and set the State of it. The method `handleChange` I have initialize object with dynamic property names. According to the code I have written when I print `e` `handleChange` method, I only see the value of the button I clicked. How Do I get both `ID` and `Value` so I can easily set state?

```
constructor(props) { 
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        radioToggleButton: 1,

    }
}

handleChange(e){

    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

...
The following code snipped is from the render() method.

```
  return(
<form onSubmit={this.savePreference}>
<FormGroup 
    controlId="meatOptionDay1"
    validationState={this.getValidationState()}
  >
        <ButtonToolbar>
            <ToggleButtonGroup className="btn-choice" type="radio" name="stateofRadio" defaultValue={this.state.radioToggleButton} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                  <ToggleButton value={1} >Op1</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton value={2}>Op2</ToggleButton>
              </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </ButtonToolbar>
    </FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your handleChange event like this

```
handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: you can set unique name of your ToggleButton and try it